# Twig: filter in an if condition

Tags: symfony, twig

I want to use an filter in an if condition in Twig. The reason for this is a Symfony2 attribute, which I can't compare directly, I have to change it beforehand. I have started with this code:

```
{% if app.request.attributes.get('_controller')|split('::')|first == 'some\controller\name' %}
  do something
{% endif %}
```

Unfortunately this does not function. So I thought I would use set before the comparison:

```
{% set controller = app.request.attributes.get('_controller')|split('::')|first %}
{% if controller == 'some\controller\name' %}
  do something
{% endif %}
{{ controller }} {# would print 'some\controller\name' #}
```

Guess what? "do something" is not printed, even if the variable *controller* now exists and has the value I compare it with. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have too much logic in the View, I'd move the logic to the controllers.  Make the view simple, it's much easier to test as well.

Comment: I don't see the sense in always assigning the same value to a template in every action of a controller, when I can have one logical expression in the view itself. That just ends in error-prone repetitions...

Comment: It should work... Are you sure to not use cache on your page ?

Comment: I'm working in the dev enviroment. No caching here. It's really strange, because the filtered expression is always printing the right value, but in a statement tag like if, it does not seem to work...

Comment: The view should not be that closely coupled to the controllers, the compare should be on a value set by the controller that describes something of interest to the view.

Comment: I'm not here to discuss software design patterns with you - I have asked a question about the technical capabilities of twig...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I tested it, Twig has a strange behavior. "\" is escaped or something like this.
I extended my twig environement with the var_dump function, check this:

```
{{ var_dump("Sybio\Bundle\WebsiteBundle\Controller\MainController") }}
//string(48) "SybioBundleWebsiteBundleControllerMainController"

{{ var_dump(app.request.attributes.get('_controller')|split('::')|first) }}
// string(52) "Sybio\Bundle\WebsiteBundle\Controller\MainController"

{{ var_dump("Sybio\\Bundle\\WebsiteBundle\\Controller\\MainController") }}
// string(52) "Sybio\Bundle\WebsiteBundle\Controller\MainController"
```

That's why your test is always false.
You need to double the backslashes of your compared string...

```
{% if app.request.attributes.get('_controller')|split('::')|first == 'some\\controller\\name' %}
  do something
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Just want to add that twig has `dump()` built-in, [here's how to enable it](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#debugging) in Symfony.